# How to make vertical bar visible on HTML Select

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a ASP.NET Panel inside I have the list box. The Panel width is fixed.  The issue is the vertical bar is not hidden since the width is small. Look at this example. http://jsfiddle.net/UnkEG/17/

Is there way to have the both horizontal bar and vertical bar always visible? Please let me know.

```
div{   
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

<div style="width:140px;">
    <select name="selectbox" size="5"  id="selectbox" >
        <option value="1">one two three four five six seven eight</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: css: `.selectbox { overflow: visible; }` will make both scrollbars visible

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow: visible`,

Or set separately for both x and y

```
overflow-x: visible
overflow-y: visible
```

**Note: The overflow property does not work properly in IE8 and earlier.**

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

**CSS**

```
div{
    width: 150px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select size="9">
        <option>Option 1 Option 1 Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2 Option 2 Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3 Option 3 Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4 Option 4 Option 4</option>
        <option>Option 5 Option 5 Option 5</option>
        <option>Option 6 Option 6 Option 6</option>
        <option>Option 7 Option 7 Option 7</option>
        <option>Option 8 Option 8 Option 8</option>
        <option>Option 9 Option 9 Option 9</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8DJ/3/)**